# How to assign value to a primitive variable

Tags: karate

I want to set a value for a primitive variable, but it will report error.

This is my code

> ```
> * def firstVersionTicketId = null
> * firstVersionUid = 'my string'
> ```

This is the error

> `no step-definition method match found for: firstVersionUid = 'my string'`

I see the object can be assigned like this in the guide https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#set:

> - def myJson = { a: '1' }
> - myJson.b = 2

So how to set value for a primitive variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
* def firstVersionUid = 'my string'
```

The example you are referring to is the setting of a JSON sub-variable, note the `.`.

Comment: But my scenario is firstly assign a value for 'firstVersionUid', and it will be reassign in other place. Seems my scenario it's not supported by karate???

Comment: @MinoChen did you try what I proposed ? in karate you can always over-write a primitive variable - but you have to use `def`.